# Likelihood estimator for inhomgeneous Poisson process

Tags: stochastic-processes, st.statistics

Assume, i have an inhomogeneous Poisson process $N(t)$ with time-dependent intensity $\lambda$, i.e.

- $ N(0) = 0$
- $ N(t)-N(s) \sim \operatorname{Poiss}(\Lambda(s,t))$
- $N$ has independent increments.

where 
$$\Lambda(s,t) = \int_s^t \lambda(\tau) d \tau.$$

Now assume $\lambda$ is of known to be of form $\lambda(\tau)=f(\tau, \boldsymbol\beta)$, for a known function $f$ and unknown vector $\boldsymbol \beta$.

I have a sample of realizations of $N$ given in an interval $[0,T_{\max}]$: ($N(t,\omega_1), \ldots, N(t,\omega_n))$.

Now here is my question: If I want to get a maximum likelihood estimator for $\boldsymbol \beta$, I can chose a set $\{t_0,\ldots,t_k\}$ with $0=t_0 < t_1 < \ldots t_k=T$ and maximize the likelihood

$$\boldsymbol \beta = \arg\max_{\boldsymbol \beta} \prod_{i=0}^{k-1} \prod_{j=1}^n \mathbb P\big(N(t_i)-N(t_{i+1}) = N(t_i, \omega_j) - N(t_{i+1}, \omega_j) \big).$$

So now I am a bit confused by the following questions:

- How does the partition of the interval $[0,T]$ affect my estimation of $\boldsymbol \beta$. Both the number of $t_j$ and also how do I distribute them on the interval?
- Is that a stupid question to ask, because I forgot something trivial?

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 1):

Letting $t\downarrow s$, we see that the conditions $Cov(N(s),N(t))=\Lambda(s,t)$ and $\Lambda(s,t)=\int_s^t \lambda(\tau)\, d\tau$ imply $Var\,N(s)=0$ for all $s$, whence $\Lambda(s,t)=0$ for all $s<t$ and thus $f(\tau,\beta)=\lambda(\tau)=0$ for all $\tau$ and $\beta$ (assuming, for instance, that $\lambda(\cdot)$ is continuous). So, there is no problem estimating $\beta$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was maybe a stupid question. I edited now, such that it hopefully makes more sense

Comment: After this change, the question makes a bit more sense. However, your double sum is not the likelihood. To get the likelihood, you need to replace the double sum by the double product (assuming you sample independently).

Comment: hmm yesterday wasnt my best of days. :-S. Thanks for the hint. I made some numerical experiments, in which it seems to not make any difference how many support points I take...

Comment: @Martin : Is $f(\tau,\beta)$ smooth in $\beta$? How do you measure/define the quality of the estimation of $\beta$?

Comment: Hi, yes $f$ is smoth in $\beta$. I am not sure what you mean with quality of estimation. It is just the maximum likelihood estimator? My question was rather if the expected value of $\beta$ dependes on my choice of $t_i$?